# Android studio V0.8 cannot create new Glass Module with error "The component Glass Module has a minimum SDK level of 19"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, google-glass, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a phone app and planning to port it to glass with some modifications. I thought creating a new Glass Module under the parent app project will save me some time and effort, since the libraries modules are already set up, and my phone app's module is always present for me to reference. However when I tries to create a Glass Module from the "New Module" dialogue a red message below says "The component Glass Module has a minimum sdk level of 19." I am unable to carry on the setup.

My project's build.gradle is very simple and does not define a min sdk :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Does anyone any idea what is preventing me from creating a new Module under the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a walk around: create a new Android Application Module, and under "Module settings" enter "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19" for Compiler sdk version. this will import the corresponding GDK for your module. This works however it is still impossible to create Glass Module directly from the New Module Dialogue.